# How to move Tomcat webapp from ROOT to elsewhere?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm currently serving a Java servlet with Tomcat. It is located in /webapps/ROOT. I would like to move it to /app, so that its URL will go from www.mydomain.com/ to www.mydomain.com/app. How can I achieve this? So far I have attempted copying the webapps/ROOT folder to webapps/app and then changing this part in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but to no avail. How can I simply move this app from / to /app ? Googling this question, I've run into references to Contexts and Hosts but I don't understand what they mean.

Comment: Just rename the ROOT.war file (or the ROOT folder) to app.war (or the folder to app). You shouldn't change anything in web.xml.

Comment: That default servlet entry in web.xml is useless though. Tomcat has already exactly this one in its own web.xml. Get rid of it altogether in your webapp's web.xml.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I was changing tomcat's web.xml.

Comment: You are not supposed to touch it as long as you're dealing with webapps, not with the server itself. It would break Tomcat sooner or later. Leave it and let it do its job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the web.xml as it was before.

Zip contents of your folder ROOT and name it app.war

Put app.war into webapps/

Restart tomcat

Browse to /app

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, this works. For my education, why does copying ROOT.war to app.war work whereas copying ROOT to app doesn't?